How to Read a Text File and Make Pandas Data Frame
Given a text file (data.txt) with the following contents:
John: 1 
Jane: 5 
Mark: 7 
Dan: 2

How can I use python to use the text file to create a data frame that would be logically equivalent to the one given by:
# Initialize data
data = {'Name': ['John', 'Jane', 'Mark', 'Dan'],
        'Count': [1, 5, 7, 2]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


As usual with your questions there's little or no effort made on your part. Stackoverflow is not a coding service

@SIGHUP I apologize, I am pretty brand new to coding and didn't know where to start. I'll try to include some effort in the future. I will say, the answers below are extremely helpful in increasing my understanding, so thats good.

Use read_csv with parameter sep for separator and names for new columns names:
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=":", names=['Name','Count'])
print (df)
   Name  Count
0  John      1
1  Jane      5
2  Mark      7
3   Dan      2

Also is possible change separator for : with optional space:
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=r":\s*", names=['Name','Count'], engine='python')

Also is possible use skipinitialspace=True, if neccessary, thank you @ouroboros1:
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=":", names=['Name','Count'], skipinitialspace=True)


To skip spaces after the delimiter, you can use skipinitialspace=True.

@ouroboros1 - thank you, added to answer.

In fact, with these data, skipping the leading space is unnecessary as pandas will take a sequence such as " 99" (note the leading space) as int64

@SIGHUP - Exactly it is reason why it is optional second and third solution. Thank you for feedback.

You can use read_table() function.
pd.read_table('data.txt', sep = ':', header=None, names=['Name', 'Count'])

Output:
    Name    Value
0   John    1
1   Jane    5
2   Mark    7
3   Dan     2

